# Node.js configuration object based on environment variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration

In the code below, I am building a NODE_ENV-sensitive config object from environment variables.

```
let username
let password
let cluster
let hosts
let databaseName
let replicaSet

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  username = process.env.ATLAS_HUB_USERNAME
  password = process.env.ATLAS_HUB_PASSWORD
  cluster = process.env.ATLAS_CLUSTER
  hosts = process.env.ATLAS_HOSTS
  databaseName = process.env.ATLAS_DATABASE
  replicaSet = process.env.ATLAS_REPLICA_SET
} else {
  username = process.env.MONGO_HUB_USERNAME
  password = process.env.MONGO_HUB_PASSWORD
  cluster = process.env.MONGO_CLUSTER
  hosts = process.env.MONGO_HOSTS
  databaseName = process.env.MONGO_DATABASE
  replicaSet = process.env.MONGO_REPLICA_SET
}
const config = { username, password, cluster, hosts, databaseName, replicaSet }
```

In this new age of fancy spread and rest operators, I hate polluting my files with code like this which repeat the same variable name multiple times and uses `let` instead of `const` for the wrong reasons, all for something simple and frequent. I could use the ternary operator to get something way better:

```
const config = {
  username:     process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.ATLAS_HUB_USERNAME : process.env.MONGO_HUB_USERNAME,
  password:     process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.ATLAS_HUB_PASSWORD : process.env.MONGO_HUB_PASSWORD,
  cluster:      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.ATLAS_CLUSTER : process.env.MONGO_CLUSTER,
  hosts:        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.ATLAS_HOSTS : process.env.MONGO_HOSTS,
  databaseName: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.ATLAS_DATABASE : process.env.MONGO_DATABASE,
  replicaSet:   process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.ATLAS_REPLICA_SET : process.env.MONGO_REPLICA_SET
}
```

But even this seems one step short of what modern js should be able to do. I'd now like to get rid of the repeated `process.env.NODE_ENV`, I just can't figure out how (apart from creating a new const with a shorter name). If I had a magic wand, I'd write something along the following lines:

```
const config = ({
  username: [process.env.MONGO_HUB_USERNAME, process.env.ATLAS_HUB_USERNAME],
  password: [process.env.MONGO_HUB_PASSWORD, process.env.ATLAS_HUB_PASSWORD],
  cluster: [process.env.MONGO_CLUSTER, process.env.ATLAS_CLUSTER],
  hosts: [process.env.MONGO_HOSTS, process.env.ATLAS_HOSTS],
  databaseName: [process.env.MONGO_DATABASE, process.env.ATLAS_DATABASE],
  replicaSet: [process.env.MONGO_REPLICA_SET, process.env.ATLAS_REPLICA_SET]
}).*[new Number(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')]
```

But I don't, and it's not even all that great, sooo, any suggestions?

I thought of using a function, like below, but this just introduces another dependency you need to internalize for a simple batch conditional assignment operation... And if the function is in-line, there is duplication across files and it's frankly just confusing.

```
function fromEach (obj, key) {
  const final = {}
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
    final[k] = obj[k][key]
  })
  return final
}
const config = fromEach({
  username: [process.env.MONGO_HUB_USERNAME, process.env.ATLAS_HUB_USERNAME],
  password: [process.env.MONGO_HUB_PASSWORD, process.env.ATLAS_HUB_PASSWORD],
  cluster: [process.env.MONGO_CLUSTER, process.env.ATLAS_CLUSTER],
  hosts: [process.env.MONGO_HOSTS, process.env.ATLAS_HOSTS],
  databaseName: [process.env.MONGO_DATABASE, process.env.ATLAS_DATABASE],
  replicaSet: [process.env.MONGO_REPLICA_SET, process.env.ATLAS_REPLICA_SET]
}, new Number(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'))
```

**Note:** I use `new Number(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')` in these examples, but I don't like it, feel free to propose something better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Years later, I'm using a different approach of expecting environment-appropriate values in the environment variables and delegating the decision to the execution context.

First, we define the values for the variables in various environments:

*.env.development*

```bash
HUB_USERNAME=usernameForDevelopment
HUB_PASSWORD=passwordForDevelopment
CLUSTER=clusterForDevelopment
HOSTS=hostsForDevelopment
DATABASE=databaseForDevelopment
REPLICA_SET=replicaSetForDevelopment
```

*.env.production*

```bash
HUB_USERNAME=usernameForProduction
HUB_PASSWORD=passwordForProduction
CLUSTER=clusterForProduction
HOSTS=hostsForProduction
DATABASE=databaseForProduction
REPLICA_SET=replicaSetForProduction
```

Next, we expect the correct file to have been used and the variables to have environment-appropriate values, removing the need for the `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` conditional altogether:

*index.js*

```js
const env = process.env
const config = {
  username:     env.HUB_USERNAME,
  password:     env.HUB_PASSWORD,
  cluster:      env.CLUSTER,
  hosts:        env.HOSTS,
  databaseName: env.DATABASE,
  replicaSet:   env.REPLICA_SET
}
```

The execution context can decide which set of variables to use.

For example, in Next.js, it looks like this:

```bash
next dev // Environment variables fetched from `.env.development`
next start // Environment variables fetched from `.env.production`
```

Or, using Node.js directly (with the help of [the `dotenv` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), don't forget to `npm i -D dotenv`):

```bash
node -r dotenv/config index.js dotenv_config_path=.env.development // DEV
node -r dotenv/config index.js dotenv_config_path=.env.production  // PROD
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, I would suggest two changes the the overall design:

- the environment variable names could have one consistent prefix, e.g. `MONGO_` and `ATLAS_`
- the keys of the config object could match the environment variable names, e.g. `databaseName` would match `MONGO_DATABASE_NAME`

If that for some reason is **not** possible, then we can hardcode the config-to-environment name mapping:

```
function getConfigurationFor(prefix) {
  const configMap = {
    username:     'HUB_USERNAME',
    password:     'HUB_PASSWORD',
    cluster:      'CLUSTER',
    hosts:        'HOSTS',
    databaseName: 'DATABASE',
    replicaSet:   'REPLICA_SET'
  }

  prefix = prefix.toUpperCase() + '_'
  return Object
    .entries(configMap)
    .reduce((result, [key, envKey]) => {
      result[key] = process.env[prefix + envKey]
      return result
    }, {})
}

const config = getConfigurationFor(
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? 'atlas'
    : 'mongo'
)
```

---

if you **can** make these design changes, then we have more flexibility: we can create a function that would read all the environment variables that start with a certain prefix and return this as a plain JavaScript object:

```
const getEnvironmentForPrefix(prefix, source) {
  const camelCase = require('lodash.camelcase')

  return Object
    .entries(source || process.env)
    .filter([key] => key.startsWith(prefix))
    .map(([key, value]) => [key.substring(prefix.length), value])
    .map(([key, value]) => [camelcase(key), value])
    .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
      result[key] = value
      return result
    }, {})    
}

const config = getEnvironmentForPrefix(
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? 'ATLAS_'
    : 'MONGO_'
)
```